# 2005 ford focus 2.0 motor

Tags: ford, focus, power-loss

I had a fuel pump installed twice ( first was faulty) now I had extremely poor acceleration going uphill and sometimes flat land after about 15 miles.  Especially while passing or around 55 mph No light, most of time I can pull over shut off restart immediately and the exstream loss gos away. It comes and gos but always uphill and getting worse

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Which fuel does it use?  Petrol / diesel?

Comment: Gas it's a 2005 ford focus 2.0 motor